# How to pivot a single row summary in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e8e49/2/0

I want to get some summary data from my table into rows instead of columns..

```
select 
  sum(n),
  avg(n),
  max(n),
  min(n)
from Table1
```

this returns a single row, multi-column result.

How can I get it into a result that's something like this:

```
Label | Res
-------------
min   | 2
max   | 3
count | 30
... etc ...
```

Comment: no pivot as is. you can union it instead

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tablefunc.html if you can create extension. that won't work on fiddle though, cos you need to create extension first

Comment: I can use the crosstab function - just can't figure out how I'd use it for this single row result

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query

Answer (score 3):

Postgres does not have a pivot trasformation...

```
    select 
      'sum' as "key",sum(n) as "value" from Table1
    union all
   select   'avg', avg(n) from Table1
    union all
      select   'max', max(n) from Table1
    union all
      select   'min', min(n) from Table1
```

or if you have superuser can try [CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tablefunc.html)